# Connect to OpenLink Virtuoso via PHP ODBC

Tags: php, apache, odbc, virtuoso, selinux

I'm getting the following error from a default install on Fedora of PHP with php-odbc and virtuoso-opensource, when connecting through Apache:

```
[unixODBC][OpenLink][Virtuoso iODBC Driver]CL033: Connect failed to localhost:1111 = localhost:1111.
```

The test code:

```
<?php
$conn   = odbc_connect('VOS', 'dba', 'dba');
echo odbc_errormsg();
$query  = 'SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.}}';
$result = odbc_exec($conn, 'CALL DB.DBA.SPARQL_EVAL(\'' . $query . '\', NULL, 0)');
?>
<ul>
<?php while (odbc_fetch_row($result)): ?>
    <li><?php echo odbc_result($result, 1) ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

ODBC config. files:

```
#/etc/odbc.ini 

[ODBC Data Sources]
VOS = Virtuoso

[VOS]
Driver = virtuoso-odbc
Description = Virtuoso Open-Source Edition
Address = localhost:1111

#/etc/odbcinst.ini 

[virtuoso-odbc]
Driver      = /usr/lib/virtodbc.so
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

ETA: A test PHP -> ODBC -> Virtuoso script works fine from the command line, problem is Apache -> PHP -> ODBC -> Virtuoso, I'm checking now that selinux etc. (a Fedora install) is not blocking the server.

Comment: Are you sure your Virtuoso instance is running? Is your firewall set to permit these connections? Note -- Virtuoso-specific questions often get better, faster response via Virtuoso-focused resources, such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php). ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - a test PHP / ODBC / Virtuoso script works fine from the command line, problem is Apache / PHP / ODBC / Virtuoso, I'm checking now that selinux etc. (a Fedora install) is not blocking the server.  There is one OpenLink support forum post with the same error http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6018#p11986 but referred to a support ticket.  If the problem is not restrictive security settings then I'll pick this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, a SELinux problem, I am somewhat new to the Fedora distribution I have installed at the moment.  The full answer is [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/80450/error-connecting-to-localhost-service/?answer=80454#post-id-80454), in summary the following command allows httpd to network connect:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```